# How do you properly restrict xcoverage package coverage in nosetests using setup.cfg?

Tags: python, code-coverage, nosetests

I've configured it so my simple unit test passes. But nosexunit.xml is reporting on test lib files. Partial output:

```
nosexcover-1.0.7-py2.6.egg/nosexcover/nosexcover    25     24     4%   5-41, 46-56
test/unit/test_setup                                13      0   100%
```

The project is split up into different modules that need to be tested independently. I'm focusing on the backend module at present. I want to restrict coverage to the lib package. A sample of the project tree:

```
project
\-- backend     # <-- module I'm testing
    \-- lib     # <-- what I want to cover
    \-- test
       \-- unit/test_setup.py       # <-- test I'm running
    \-- setup.py
    \-- setup.cfg
\--reporting
    \-- setup.py
    \-- setup.cfg
```

I'm running the tests from the dir named backend:

```
project/backend$ python setup.py nosetests -s --tests=unit/test_setup.py
```

Nosetests is configured in setup.cfg as follows

```
[nosetests]
# locating tests
where=./test
include=^unit.*

# coverage
cover-package=lib
cover-html=1
cover-html-dir=htmlcov
with-xcoverage=1
xcoverage-file=coverage.xml
with-xunit=1
xunit-file=nosexunit.xml
cover-erase=1
```

I've got a feeling one of the path settings is off. I'm assuming the `where` and `cover-package` settings are relative to the location of `setup.py` (also where I'm running the test) and `include` is relative to `where`.

Nosetests documentation wasn't much help. I hope someone can set me straight here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I had this configured correctly after all. The problem seems to be that, for my overly simplified smoke test, I wasn't actually importing anything from the module to which I restricted coverage.

Apparently, in this case, when coverage is nil, rather than report that boring fact, nosexcoverage or nosetests decides to give you a coverage report about a bunch of other stuff instead.

By adding an import statement for the module I wanted covered, I got the proper coverage report:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
XML: nosexunit.xml
Name        Stmts   Miss  Cover   Missing
-----------------------------------------
lib             0      0   100%   
lib.blank       1      0   100%   
-----------------------------------------
TOTAL           1      0   100%   
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.008s
```